# React Native invalid key to CameraRoll getPhotos callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm relatively new to React and I'm trying to get my React Native app to access images from the camera roll, but I keep getting an error that says **"Invalid props.image key 'filename' supplied to 'CameraRoll.getPhotos callback"** and can't figure out how to fix it.

Here's my code:

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: [],
    };
  }

  storeImages(data) {
    const assets = data.edges;
    const images = assets.map( asset => asset.node.image );
    this.setState({
        images: images,
    });
 }

 logImageError(err) {
   console.log(err);
 }

  onButtonPress() {
    const fetchParams = {
      first: 3,
    };

    CameraRoll.getPhotos(fetchParams, this.storeImages, this.logImageError);

  }
```

Here's the article I used to get started: https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/accessing-iphone-camera-roll-images-react-native

Also, here's a screenshot of the full error:

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUlhR.jpg)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That article is almost 2 years old and the CameraRoll has changed since then. I haven't really worked with it but I believe you have to set it up like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: [],
    };
  }

  onButtonPress = () => {
    const fetchParams = {
      first: 3,
    };

    CameraRoll.getPhotos(fetchParams) //Use promises instead of callbacks
      .then((data) => {
        const assets = data.edges;
        const images = assets.map( asset => asset.node.image );
        this.setState({
          images: images,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```